# How to create a new object from an array by calculating specific fiels

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with the following structure

```
[
{
caseStatus: "Closed",
caseDays: 5,
caseRate: 40
},
{
caseStatus: "Closed",
caseDays: 8,
caseRate: 25
},
{
caseStatus: "Active",
caseDays: 5,
caseRate: undefined
}
]
```

I want to derive the following results.

1. Number of cases with caseStatus as "Active" ==>countActive
2. Number of cases with case status as "Closed" ==> countClosed
3. Sum of caseDays for the cases with status "Closed" ==> ClosedCaseDaysSum
4. Sum of caseRate for the cases with status "Closed" ==> ClosedCaseRateSum

```
{
countActive:1,
countClosed:2,
ClosedCaseDaysSum: 13,
ClosedCaseRateSum: 65
}
```

Comment: with `reduce` it's pretty straightforward. If you get stuck edit your question with your attempt

Comment: Is the output that you provided is correct for the input?

Comment: Yes, Output is correct.@Nitheesh

Comment: @creativated whats the logic for countActive:1,
countClosed:2,

Comment: @Nitheesh maybe he wants to consolidate the response to show it on a dashboard most probably.

Comment: There are freelancing websites if you want a task done. People that are trying to help here require a sample of your code which you need to show as proof that you tried to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), as follows:

```js
const data = [
  { caseStatus: "Closed", caseDays: 5, caseRate: 40 },
  { caseStatus: "Closed", caseDays: 8, caseRate: 25 },
  { caseStatus: "Active", caseDays: 5, caseRate: undefined }
];

const result = { countActive: 0, countClosed: 0, ClosedCaseDaysSum: 0, ClosedCaseRateSum: 0 };

data.forEach(item => {
  if (item.caseStatus === "Closed") {
    result.ClosedCaseDaysSum += item.caseDays;
    result.ClosedCaseRateSum += item.caseRate;
    result.countClosed++;
  } else if (item.caseStatus === "Active") {
    result.countActive++;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.reduce` implementation.

**Logic**

- Loop through the array
- Check `caseStatus` of each each node.
- Update `ClosedCaseDaysSum`, `ClosedCaseRateSum`, `countClosed` for `caseStatus === 'Closed'`
- Update `countActive` for `caseStatus === "Active"`

```js
const data = [
  {
    caseStatus: "Closed",
    caseDays: 5,
    caseRate: 40
  },
  {
    caseStatus: "Closed",
    caseDays: 8,
    caseRate: 25
  },
  {
    caseStatus: "Active",
    caseDays: 5,
    caseRate: undefined
  }
];
const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.caseStatus === "Closed") {
    acc.ClosedCaseDaysSum += curr.caseDays;
    acc.ClosedCaseRateSum += curr.caseRate;
    acc.countClosed++;
  } else if(curr.caseStatus === "Active") {
    acc.countActive++;
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  countActive: 0,
  countClosed: 0,
  ClosedCaseDaysSum: 0,
  ClosedCaseRateSum: 0
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use reduce function.

```js
const data = [
    {
    caseStatus: "Closed",
    caseDays: 5,
    caseRate: 40
    },
    {
    caseStatus: "Closed",
    caseDays: 8,
    caseRate: 25
    },
    {
    caseStatus: "Active",
    caseDays: 5,
    caseRate: undefined
    }
];

const result = data.reduce((total, val) => {
    val.caseStatus === 'Closed' ? total.countClosed++ : total.countActive++;
    if(val.caseStatus === 'Closed' && val.caseDays !== undefined) total.ClosedCaseDaysSum += val.caseDays;
    if(val.caseStatus === 'Closed' && val.caseRate !== undefined) total.ClosedCaseRateSum += val.caseRate;
    return total;
}, { countActive: 0, countClosed: 0, ClosedCaseDaysSum: 0, ClosedCaseRateSum: 0});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're summing the 'Active` case days as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you normalize your aggregation object this becomes trivial by simply aggregating into the `result[c.caseStatus]` property.
This also serves to normalize the resulting property names ie: `Active.count`, `Closed.count`, `Closed.caseDays` etc.

```js
const input = [{caseStatus: "Closed",caseDays: 5,caseRate: 40},{caseStatus: "Closed",caseDays: 8,caseRate: 25},{caseStatus: "Active",caseDays: 5,caseRate: undefined}];

result = {
  Active: {
    count: 0,
    caseDays: 0,
    caseRate: 0
  },
  Closed: {
    count: 0,
    caseDays: 0,
    caseRate: 0
  }
};

for (const c of input) {
  result[c.caseStatus].count++;
  result[c.caseStatus].caseDays += c.caseDays ?? 0;
  result[c.caseStatus].caseRate += c.caseRate ?? 0;
}

console.log(result);
```